# A question about continuous functions on topological spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I studied continuous functions on metric spaces, and on topological spaces. On metric spaces, a function is continuous iff it satisfies the following condition:

$\quad\quad\quad x_n \to a \;\Rightarrow\; f(x_{n_j}) \to  f(a),$  for a subsequence of $f(x_n)$

When is it true for topological spaces? It it true when we have Hausdoff Second-countable spaces?

Comment: The condition you state doesn't seem correct (should be for every sequence $x_n\to a$, and taking subsequence in the rest os the statement doesn't seem right). True for Hausdorrf second countable or even only first countable spaces. Not true for Hausdorff spaces in general.

Comment: @Mirko Certainly in metric spaces, it is indeed true that $f$ is continuous if and only if, for all $x_n \to a$, there exists some subsequence $(x_{n_j})$ such that $f(x_{n_j}) \to f(a)$. It's not the standard sequential continuity definition, but it is equivalent (in metric spaces, at least).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition you've stated is equivalent to sequential continuity, for any map $f$ between general topological spaces $X$ and $Y$. Clearly, sequential continuity implies this condition, as we can simply take the improper subsequence (i.e. the whole sequence), and the condition is satisfied.

We can prove the inverse, to prove the converse. If we failed sequential continuity, then there must exist some $x_n \to x$ such that $f(x_n) \not\to f(x)$. Then, there exists some open $\mathcal{V} \ni f(x)$ such that, for all $N$, $n \ge N$ does not imply that $f(x_n) \in \mathcal{V}$. So, for all $k$, we can choose some $n_k \ge k$ such that $f(x_{n_k}) \notin \mathcal{V}$. By choosing $n_k$ to be larger than $n_{k-1}$, we form a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ such that $f(x_{n_k}) \notin \mathcal{V}$ for all $k$.

Now, $x_{n_k}$ is a sequence that violates the condition: every (sub)subsequence of $f(x_{n_k})$ will fail to even intersect $\mathcal{V}$, let alone be eventually contained in $\mathcal{V}$, let alone converge to $f(x)$. This proof is essentially what I'd use in the metric space case.

So, the question reduces to, in which spaces do we expect sequential continuity to agree with continuity? Normally, the latter is weaker (i.e. continuous maps are automatically sequentially continuous). However, if $X$ is a [sequential space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space), e.g. a *first*-countable topological space (no Hausdorff necessary), then sequential continuity is equivalent to continuity. Indeed, here is a relevant quote from the page:

> Every continuous map is sequentially continuous although in general, the converse may fail to hold. In fact, a space $(X,\tau)$ is a sequential space if and only if it has the following universal property for sequential spaces:
>
> For every topological space $(Y,\sigma)$ and every map $f:X\to Y$, the map $f:(X,\tau )\to (Y,\sigma )$ is continuous if and only if it is sequentially continuous.

So, indeed, sequential spaces are precisely the class of spaces you're interested in.